# How to make a custom legend with a squared box followed by a text?

Tags: color, boxes, legend

I'm trying to make one of that legends that we can find in some graphics such as bar plots.

[image]

Just to clarify, I'm not displaying a plot. I have to present a schedule, which is defined trough a table environment, and each cell is filled with a color representing its  current state. Then, I need a legend for these colors.

This is my current approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\cbox}[1]{\fcolorbox{black}{#1}{\null}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \cbox{white} Done.
    \cbox{gray!80} In Progress.
    \cbox{gray!40} Future.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And that is what I got:

[image]

As can be seen, the result isn't good.

I wondering how to obtain the properly result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\cbox}[1]{\raisebox{\depth}{\fcolorbox{black}{#1}{\null}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \cbox{white} Done.\quad
    \cbox{gray!80} In Progress.\quad
    \cbox{gray!40} Future.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting "Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `\vrule '. \cbox" when I use the code inside the \frame, any suggestions?

Comment: Could post a minimal code reproducing the problem?